# Access Denied Magento Admin after domain change: correct password

Tags: magento, admin

After migrating from an amazon instance to GoDaddy hosting, I am unable to login to Magento backend when using the same username and password,

Adding a new user with a new password gives the same error: access denied

web/unsecure/base_url are set correctly in the database table core_config_table

My cookies are setup as follows

web/cookie/cookie_lifetime  3600
web/cookie/cookie_path  NULL
web/cookie/cookie_domain    NULL
web/cookie/cookie_httponly  1
web/cookie/cookie_restriction   0

Please let me know any thoughts you may have as I have searched google many times and none of the guides help, and I am starting to feel like I am the only one with this specific issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions like this are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Comment: I disagree, as they work in hand with a lot of programming, but ok.

Comment: Keyboards work in hand (pardon the pun) with programming, but it doesn't mean that questions about keyboards are programming-related. You need to make sure that your question is specifically about programming.

Comment: is there any way someone can move this to magento stack overflow?

Comment: I don't know if it can be moved automatically or not.

Answer (score 2):

Found the [Solution](https://gist.github.com/mapav/7464484) myself after many weeks,

Save this file as newadmin.php in your magento root, then uncomment and replace the credentials with the ones you want, then go to example.com/newadmin.php

Voila!!!

The reason is because administrator permissions were contravened, as far as I know this is the only way to add a working user.

Unfortunately one problem led to the next and I started getting index.php  inserted into all of my links when I go into admin panel ex:

example.com/index.php/admin/********

I would be fine with this if it didn't send it to a 404 page, the correct page is:

example.com/admin/********

when I remove index.php from the url it works, but if I click on any link or try to save chages in admin panel, it reinserts the index.php in the url and doesn't POST anything to the page, because it gets sent to a 404 page

Click [This Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64475/remove-index-php-from-links-in-admin-panel/64512#64512) if you want to follow my bug-fixing adventures:

Answer (score 0):

try after delete var/* folder for remove cache

if not worked then change password from db admin_user table then try it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you name your database and users exactly the same as before?

Some CPanels will automatically choose the first part of the MSQL database for you...

check app/etc/local.xml and see if it's all correct